# How to get the GitHub data from various URLs and stored in the single mongoDB

Tags: github, talend, github-api, rest-client

I'm trying to get the GitHub data using Talend big data. The thing is, i have multiple URLs,because used each URL to take some values & stored into single mongoDB. The below order only i'm going to try & get the informations,

```
https://api.github.com/users/sample/repos
https://api.github.com/repos/sample/awesome-ciandcd/commits
https://api.github.com/repos/sample/awesome-ciandcd/contributors
```

Each URLs are giving the single JSONArray with multiple data format.Please give some suggestion to do this. I've already tried with sub-jobs component. But not get clear job.

My Output Should be like,

```
{
    "gitname": "sample",
    "gitType" : "User",
    "password": "password",
    "repoCount": 3,
    "repositoryDetails": [
        {
            "repoName": "MergeCheckRepository",
            "fileCount": 10,
            "branchCount": 6,
            "releaseCount": 2,
            "commitsCount": 10,
            "contributorsCount": 3,
            "totalPulls": 1,
            "mergeCount": 1,
            "totalIssues": 12,
            "closedIssueCount": 3,
            "watchersCount": 1,
            "stargazersCount": 4,
            "contributorsDetails": [
                {
                    "login": "sample",
                    "avatarURL": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/30261572?v=4",
                    "contributions": 3
                }
            ],
            "commitDetails": [
                {
                    "name": "sample",
                    "email": "sampletest@test.com",
                    "date": "2017-07-20T09:09:09Z"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "repoName": "Dashboard",
            "filecount": 19,
            "branchCount": 4,
            "releasecount": 2,
            "commitsCount": 5,
            "contributorsCount": 3,
            "totalPulls": 1,
            "totalIssues": 2,
            "closedIssueCount": 3,
            "watchersCount": 1,
            "stargazersCount": 4,
            "contributorsDetails": [
                {
                    "login": "sample",
                    "avatarURL": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/30261572?v=4",
                    "contributions": 3
                },
                {
                    "login": "Dashboard",
                    "avatarURL": "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/30261572?v=4",
                    "contributions": 3
                }
            ],
            "commitDetails": [
                {
                    "name": "sample",
                    "email": "sampletest@test.com",
                    "date": "2017-07-14T09:09:09Z"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Dashboard",
                    "email": "prakash.thangasamy@test.com",
                    "date": "2017-07-19T09:09:09Z"
                },
                {
                    "name": "testrepo",
                    "email": "test.dashboard@test.com",
                    "date": "2017-07-20T09:09:09Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How to achieve this one with sub-job? Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: i dont understand your question here. can u show us the mapping of input URL data to given output json?

Comment: This output is expected only. What i'm saying is, each URL have some values. finally i need to store all the values into single DB.